# Redhat Grub not working after Fresh Install

Tags: rhel, grub

Today i installed redhat on one server this server will be used on DR site as a backup.

System has 2 HDD with 500GB space and I created  the RAID0 and after that i completed the installation. But after the installation I had to reboot the server but Just after the BIOS screen I got Black screen with just GRUB written.

Raid0 is used

Filesystem Structure

- /boot 100M (Normally I assign 500M but this time I assign only 100M because the size of /boot rarely increases)
- swap  8GB

VolGroup0 has two LVMs

- / has 50G size (LogicalVol00)
- /u001 has 400G+ size (LogVol01)

I found information on redhat pages. That /boot cannot be used on RAID0

[How to install Grub](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-grub-installing.html)

[image]

Comment: provide more information: raid0? Hardware or Software? LVM being used? how was the /boot partition specified?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention RAID type.Its HW raid and I updated the Question

Comment: And boot partition has size of 100M.

Comment: have you tried to boot from dvd and resintall grub? Is the partition marked as active from the fdisk side?

Comment: No i didn't reinstall the Grub. And not sure of active disk. Because server is not booting. But from hardware level the disk is active

Comment: That is not hardware RAID. It is fakeraid.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, What do you mean it is a fake Raid??? Will you please explain whats in your mind. How can a Hardware raid be a Fake.

Comment: @UmairMustafa "Fake" RAID is a system where you can set up the disks in the BIOS but the actual work is done by a software driver. This software driver comes from the BIOS maker and is probably significantly worse than the software raid code that ships with Linux. In this case, your best bet is to reset the BIOS to plain drives and configure software RAID in the RHEL installer.

Comment: @mattdm Thanks for shring information Fake RAID i was not aware about this.